# Can I dismiss the iPhone keyboard by touching the background of DialogViewController (MonoTouch.Dialog)?

Tags: keyboard, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MonoTouch.Dialog: Dismissing keyboard by touching anywhere in DialogViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824092/monotouch-dialog-dismissing-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-in-dialogviewcontroll)

I'm using DialogViewController from MonoTouch.Dialogs. I'd like to be able to dismiss the keyboard by clicking on the background of the dialog.

I usually employ the technique of filling the view with a large custom button and placing it behind all the other elements. However, I can't make this work in the DialogViewController. I did this in LoadView and it just froze all the other controls.

Is there a relatively straightforward way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 7):

In view controller:

```
public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);

        myField.ResignFirstResponder();
    }
```

Edit: From what I've read, you can use the TouchesBegan event for the cell subview instead of the table itself.  I'm not positive that works.  Good luck :)

Comment: +1 for actually having it in .net :)

Comment: +1 as it's a neat approach to the more general problem. However, it doesn't solve my problem with MonoTouch.Dialog. This is descended from UITableViewController, which doesn't seem to receive the TouchesBegan event.

Comment: -1 Doesn't work for MonoTouch.Dialog which is what the original question was asking.

Answer (score 1):

miguel.de.icaza answered this question on a different thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864640/1134836.

His solution:

> ```
>    var tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer ();
>    tap.AddTarget (() =>{
>        dvc.View.EndEditing (true);
>    });
>    dvc.View.AddGestureRecognizer (tap);
> ```

Comment: You could help us out by flagging the question as a duplicate, instead of posting a duplicate answer to a duplicate question.

Comment: I have never done that before. I assume it is just the flag link under the question?

Comment: Yes.  Use the "Other" option in the flagging dialog.