# Can the keyboard be dismissed by touching outside of the cell in MonoTouch.Dialog?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MonoTouch.Dialog: Dismissing keyboard by touching anywhere in DialogViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824092/monotouch-dialog-dismissing-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-in-dialogviewcontroll)

I noticed that when touching outside of the table cell (which I suppose is the 'section'), the touchesBegan method does not get called so I can't call `EndEditing` or `ResignFirstReponder`.

I am creating a multiline entry element; because of this, the return key goes to a new line instead of "returning". This is the intended behavior. However, I have no way to dismiss the keyboard then.

I noticed in the settings for menu on the iPhone (General->Keyboard->Shortcuts) or when entering credentials, that touching in the outer area does not resign the responder. Does this mean that this is a limitation of iOS as a whole (or Apple just didn't see fit in these instances)?

Is there anyway to do this?

There is, what I gather, an identical question here but no one came up with a valid answer:
[Can I dismiss the iPhone keyboard by touching the background of DialogViewController (MonoTouch.Dialog)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463778/can-i-dismiss-the-iphone-keyboard-by-touching-the-background-of-dialogviewcontro)

Maybe in a year and a half someone has solved it?

Comment: Can you show the "next" button instead ... like when you're filling in a webform in Safari?

Comment: I haven't tried it. I didn't know if the next/done button could have different functionality than the Enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

miguel.de.icaza answered this question on a different thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864640/1134836.

His solution:

> ```
>    var tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer ();
>    tap.AddTarget (() =>{
>        dvc.View.EndEditing (true);
>    });
>    dvc.View.AddGestureRecognizer (tap);
> ```

Comment: you must also add dvc.CancelsTouchesInView = false; otherwise this will cancel all your other clicks on the page!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

- Put a "Done" button somewhere
- Hook up the touch event on the background of your view to dismiss

I think the first option is better, since it is what Safari does.

You can attach a toolbar to the top of the keyboard to simulate what Safari does with `InputAccessoryView`.  Here is an example of doing this in Obj-C (should be easy to port): http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html

It may not work for your layout, however, if screen real estate is tight.  Go with option #2 in that case.